# Earliest Timestamp supported in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, timestamp

I work with different databases in a number of different time zones (and periods of time) and one thing that normally originates problems, is the date/time definition.

For this reason, and since a date is a reference to a starting value, to keep track of how it was calculated, I try to store the base date; i.e.: the minimum date supported in that particular computer/database;

If I am seeing it well, this depends on the RDBMS and on the particular storage of the type.
In SQL Server, I found a couple of ways of calculating this "base date";

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 0)
```

or

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 0, 0 )
```

or even a cast like this:

```
DECLARE @300 BINARY(8) 
SET @300 = 0x00000000 + CAST(300 AS BINARY(4))
set @dt=(SELECT CAST(@300 AS DATETIME) AS BASEDATE)
print CAST(@dt AS NVARCHAR(100))
```

(where @dt is a datetime variable)

My question is, is there a similar way of calculating the base date in PostgreSQL, i.e.: the value that is the minimum date supported and is on the base of all calculations?

From the description of the [`date` type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html), I can see that the minimum date supported is 4713 BC, but is there a way of getting this value programmatically (for instance as a formatted date string), as I do in SQL Server?

Comment: You may well call this "0 date" a base date in SQL Server but if you think it is also the minimum date supported (and from your wording, it does seem like you do), you are mistaken. It would convert to `1900-01-01`, and `smalldatetime` is the only date/time type that can't handle dates earlier than that. The arguably more widely used `datetime` supports dates down to `1753-01-01`, and the newer types `date`, `datetime2`, `datetimeoffset` support values down to `0001-01-01`, just FYI.

Comment: Since I am looking for a reference, rather than a minimum value (although I though the minimum value could serve as a reference...), I will stick to this one: select to_timestamp(0)::date;

Answer (score 29):

[The manual states the values](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) as:

- Low value: 4713 BC
- High value: 294276 AD

with the caveat, as Chris noted, that `-infinity` is also supported.

See the **note** later in the same page in the manual; the above is only true if you are using *integer timestamps*, which are the default in all vaguely recent versions of PostgreSQL. If in doubt:

```
SHOW integer_datetimes;
```

will tell you. If you're using floating point datetimes instead, you get greater range and less (non-linear) precision. Any attempt to work out the minimum programatically must cope with that restriction.

PostgreSQL does not just let you cast zero to a timestamp to get the minimum possible timestamp, nor would this make much sense if you were using floating point datetimes. You *can* use the julian date conversion function, but this gives you the *epoch* not the *minimum time*:

```
postgres=> select to_timestamp(0);
      to_timestamp      
------------------------
 1970-01-01 08:00:00+08
(1 row)
```

because it accepts negative values. You'd think that giving it negative maxint would work, but the results are surprising to the point where I wonder if we've got a wrap-around bug lurking here:

```
postgres=> select to_timestamp(-922337203685477);
          to_timestamp           
---------------------------------
 294247-01-10 12:00:54.775808+08
(1 row)

postgres=> select to_timestamp(-92233720368547);
          to_timestamp           
---------------------------------
 294247-01-10 12:00:54.775808+08
(1 row)

postgres=> select to_timestamp(-9223372036854);
         to_timestamp         
------------------------------
 294247-01-10 12:00:55.552+08
(1 row)

postgres=> select to_timestamp(-922337203685);
ERROR:  timestamp out of range
postgres=> select to_timestamp(-92233720368);
          to_timestamp           
---------------------------------
 0954-03-26 09:50:36+07:43:24 BC
(1 row)

postgres=> select to_timestamp(-9223372036);
         to_timestamp         
------------------------------
 1677-09-21 07:56:08+07:43:24
(1 row)
```

(Perhaps related to the fact that to_timestamp takes a double, even though timestamps are stored as integers these days?).

I think it's possibly wisest to just let the timestamp range be any timestamp you don't get an error on. After all, the range of valid timestamps is not continuous:

```
postgres=> SELECT TIMESTAMP '2000-02-29';
      timestamp      
---------------------
 2000-02-29 00:00:00
(1 row)

postgres=> SELECT TIMESTAMP '2001-02-29';
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "2001-02-29"
LINE 1: SELECT TIMESTAMP '2001-02-29';
```

so you can't assume that just because a value is between two valid timestamps, it is its self valid.

Comment: In fact it is really odd, that PostgreSQL accepts values that extend the allowed interval, rather than throwing an error. I think it would make sense to calculate the minimum date, as the date calculated from the minimum supported integer (or as Craig's answer suggest, BigInt). In the PostgreSQL 9.3 manual, it is stated that the minimum supported BigInt is -9223372036854775808. Therefore, I should be able to calculate the minimum date like this: "select to_timestamp(-9223372036854775808)::date", which gives as a result "294247-01-10", not matching with the suggested 4713 BC from the manual!!

Comment: @doublebyte Made even weirder by the output of `select extract(epoch from TIMESTAMP '294247-01-10');`. Not convinced by the correctness of the date functions at extreme values.

Comment: I discovered through trial and error that the min and max values for postresql 14.0 are actually `4714-11-24 00:00:00 BC` and `294276-12-31 23:59:58.999552` respectively. You can reproduce this using `SELECT to_timestamp(-210866803201)` and `SELECT to_timestamp(9224318015999)`. This is helpful because the docs don't mention the other time components of the limits (e.g. day of year or time of day).

Answer (score 20):

The earliest timestamp is '-infinity'.  This is a special value.  The other side is 'infinity' which is later than any specific timestamp.

I don't know of a way of getting this programaticly.  I would just use the value hard-coded the way you might use NULL.  That means you have to handle infinities on the client side though.

Comment: Thanks. And to add to this, the following are legel queries: `select ('-infinity'::timestamptz) > ('2000-01-01'::timestamptz)` and `select ('infinity'::timestamptz) > ('2000-01-01'::timestamptz)` producing `true` and `false` respectively on `PostgreSQL 9.6.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit`.

Comment: Update on the above comment, those now correctly return false and true respectively on 13.3