# What is the Date MIN and MAX values in UTC Format?

Tags: postgresql

I want to set default value in a table's columns in PostgreSQL database. I have searched for datetime MIN and MAX value everywhere but I couldn't find date in  UTC format.

Can anyone help on this for MIN and MAX datetime values?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686635/earliest-timestamp-supported-in-postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-infinity` for something in the past (the "min" value), and `infinity` for something in the future (the "max" value):

```
create table some_table
(
  some_old_date   date not null default '-infinity',
  expires_on      date not null default 'infinity'
);
```

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-datetime.html#id-1.5.7.13.18.8)

> ```
> infinity    date, timestamp   later than all other time stamps<br>
> -infinity   date, timestamp   earlier than all other time stamps
> ```

Comment: i have already set database value to infinity and -infinity but it is getting problem in conversation while server side request for the data for the dates so to avoid it i want to use MIN and MAX values.

Comment: Do you have any extension that could help on date conversion while dates are render to server side

Comment: See the link Jonesopolis posted in his comment. If you can't use `infinity` your question is a duplicate of that other question.